# HTTPS proxy with caddy

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2, caddy

I am working with a Golang app and Caddy as the HTTP server. The golang app rejects every http connection, it only can be used over HTTPS. This app is a kind of API/service that is consumed by other apps. As, it requires HTTPS I installed Caddy so I can take advantage of the automatic SSL certificate and use proxy to switch between the ports.

The application is running in the port 9000, so, the consumers will only writte `mysite.com` and caddy should be in charge of redirect that petitions to the port 9000 but maintaining the HTTPS. The configuration in caddy for the site is:

```
mysite.com {
    proxy / :9000 {
        max_fails 1
    }
    log logfile
}
```

Nevertheless, it seems like when the proxy is made the HTTPS is lost. I checked the logs for the application (no the logs of caddy) and I get this:

```
http: TLS handshake error from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx: tls: oversized record received with length 21536
```

So, based in this error, to me looks like the HTTP proxy  made by caddy is losing the HTTPS. What can I do?

Comment: To be clear is port 9000 listening http or https?

Comment: If it's listening to https, you should try `proxy / https://localhost:9000`

Comment: @captncraig HTTPS. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [caddy docs](https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy)

> **to** is the destination endpoint to proxy to. At least one is required,
>   but multiple may be specified. If a scheme (http/https) is not
>   specified, http is used. Unix sockets may also be used by prefixing
>   "unix:".

So maybe it is sending **http** requests to the proxied **https** endpoint.

Does

```
mysite.com {
    proxy / https://localhost:9000 {
        max_fails 1
    }
    log logfile
}
```

fix it?

If that is the case, you may not strictly need your app on :9000 to listen https. It may simplify your deployment or cert management to just have it listen http and have caddy manage all the certs.

Comment: Or get rid of caddy, since you're just using the Go http server to proxy the Go http server which doesn't get you any benefit.

Comment: @Adrian presumably he likes the Let's Encrypt integration from caddy. Which could be gotten in other ways in his own code, but caddy is pretty easy to throw in.

Comment: So is autocert, plus, *OP is already exposing HTTPS from their own app*, which is the problem stated (Caddy is sending HTTP traffic when the app expects HTTPS), which means *they already have to deal with certs*. In the scenario given, Caddy adds zero value.

Comment: Or OP could [embed Caddy](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/wiki/Embedding-Caddy-in-your-Go-program)